# nginx + php-fpm. How to send part of html page and after the rest?

Tags: php, nginx

I have server with nginx and php-fpm runing. What I am trying to achieve is to send page header (site name and navigation block) first, then do some logic and send the rest of the page.

I have tried to echo first part of html, then flush output in php, then sleep(5) and send the rest of the page, but still browsers show the page only when they get full page (after sleep finishes and the rest of the page is echoed)

Here: http://php.net/flush people advise to set in php.ini

```
output_buffering = Off 
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

and in nginx.conf

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

I tried it and still same result. The page is displayed only when browser gets it whole.

Also I thought that it might be because browser gets the page header but do not render it because small amount of data is sent so I intentionally increased header size to 50kb this didn't help me either.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. Here is what I had to do:

PHP code:

```
ob_start();
$this->outputHeader();
ob_end_flush();
flush();
```

nginx.conf:

```
fastcgi_keep_conn on;
gzip off;
```

NOTE: php and nginx settings that I posted in my question didn't help. So I reverted those values to initial state.